# In San Francisco, I’m building stairs with a top landing. How big should the landing be?

Tags: deck

In San Francisco, We’re planning to build exterior back stairs from the second floor going to ground floor (about 61” elevation which is about 7-8 steps).  With a 32” door opening outward toward the stairs, what dimensions should the landing be?  I imagine there needs to be clearance so the width of the door plus some.  I read in some places require the width of the door plus 18”.  What is the minimum in SF?  Or what SHOULD be the extra clearance be?

Comment: What is a "GE"?

Comment: Is ADA access required in this building?

Answer (score 3):

You need a 36" minimum deep landing, regardless of the door size. The width of the landing should be at least 36", but no narrower than the stair. Also, if your deck door is an egress door, the landing can't be more than 1 1/2" below the interior floor elevation.

Comment: Naomi is correct. (See ICC R311.7.6 Landings.) The risers can’t be more than 8” and treads less than 9”. The handrail needs to be between 30” and 38”...you’re getting a Building Permit, right? They can help you with nosing dimensions, etc.

Comment: @naomi-hansen, so if I understand you correctly, 36" is the minimum but probably not the most optimal correct?  Because my door is 32", say I open it, exit the door, I only have 4" of space for me to turn around and shut the door.  Can you tell me where you got your source?  Is this for SF?  To the second comment, I didn't know you can go 1.5 below the interior floor elevation, again probably not optimal because that's a doozey to step down.  Where did you find that requirement?  I guess in general, does San Francisco have different rules than say the ICC?

Comment: I believe Naomi is correct the landing size needs to be wider than the door and many are only 36", yes there is not enough to completely open the door in some cases but you are not on multiple steps when swinging the door.